# Change text of <h1> if screen is reduced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code trying to change the text of an h1 if the screen is reduced in size, here's the actual code I have, but is not working. Someone could help me to correct it and to understand it? thanks!

HTML

```
<h1 id="text1">Test</h1>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
if($(window).width() <= 500){
$('#text1').Text('testing');  
}else{
$('#text1').Text('buuu');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to work along with `window` resize event. Other option is using CSS pseudo code.

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #text1:after {
    content: "foo";
  }
}
@media (max-width: 499px) {
  #text1:after {
    content: "bar";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="text1"></h1>
```

**Edited** As per `Niet the Dark Absol` suggestion.

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  #text1 > .tiny {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 499px) {
  #text1 > .big {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="text1">
  <span class="big">Bigger Content</span>
  <span class="tiny">Smaller Content</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: I would suggest using `<span class="big">` and `class="small"` and setting them to `display:inline` or `display:none` as needed. That way, the text is in the HTML, where it should be.

Comment: not too sure that an empty tag is a good idea, won't be readable by any other media (i'm blind, read text please ..., search engines ... well no key words !!)   ... span duplicates content  :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe CSS could help you here:

---

use `data-` attributes to validate HTML5 and mediaqueries to show its value. Old text-indent method to erase at screen text hold in the tag itself.

You can use it without `id` or `class` for entire site, but `data-` attribute will need to be there and filled, else a `class` to set wherever needed, or `id` for a single use.

```css
 @media all and (max-width:500px) { 
  h1 {
    text-indent:-9999px;
  }
  h1:before {
    content:attr(data-text);
    text-indent:0;
    float:left;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 data-text="short text">My long text stands here</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the window's resizing events. Pretty easy to do it with `jquery`.
Try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 500){
        $('#text1').Text('testing');  
    }
    else {
        $('#text1').Text('buuu');
    }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/puzanajepe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Hi there thanks:)! But I'm testing and is not working:( some possible reason?

Comment: @Eugenio have you set up and established JQuery correctly, and (possibly) wrapped this functon within a `document ready` function?

Comment: @Eugenio, check the jsBIN it's working well. Just check in your `html` if you have included the `jquery` library